# Deadlock - is this program deadlock able?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is it possible that a deadlock occurs in this code?

I ran it multiple times and didn't have one, but the task asks for an explanation whether or not a deadlock situation is possible.

```
public class DeadlockTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReentrantLock[] locks = new ReentrantLock[3]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        locks[i] = new ReentrantLock(); 
    }
    WorkerThread[] threads = new WorkerThread[3]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        threads[i] = new WorkerThread(locks[i], locks[(i+1)%3]);
        threads[i].start();
    }
  }
}

class WorkerThread extends Thread {
   private ReentrantLock l1;
   private ReentrantLock l2;
      public WorkerThread(ReentrantLock l1, ReentrantLock l2) {
         this.l1 = l1;
         this.l2 = l2; 
      }
   public void run() {
     l1.lock();
     l2.lock();
     System.out.println("Working now.");
     l1.unlock();
     l2.unlock();
   } 
}
```

Comment: It’s a simplified variant of the well-known dining philosophers. There used to be 5 of them rather than 3, but in this case it makes no difference. You may want to search the web for `dining philosophers`. Lots of interesting stuff to read.

Comment: There are [4 well-known conditions for deadlock](http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/O.F.Rana/os/lectureos12/node2.html): which of these conditions do you think apply (or not) for this code?

Comment: I get the feeling this was a school assignment question

Comment: thanks a lot guys i figured it out. the 4 conditions helped really well! thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is definitely a possibility of deadlock here:

- thread 0 will try and hold locks 0 and 1, in this order;
- thread 1 will try and hold locks 1 and 2, in this order;
- thread 2 will try and hold locks 2 and 0, in this order.

Recall that even though in code you schedule threads to run "one after the other", the underlying scheduler may choose otherwise. Also, it is not because a thread is currently executed that *all* of its code is executed.

This scenario is possible:

- thread 1 holds lock 1;
- thread 2 holds lock 2;
- thread 1 tries and holds lock 2: it cannot --> thread is blocked;
- thread 0 holds lock 0;
- thread 2 tries and holds lock 0: it cannot --> thread is blocked;
- thread 0 tries and holds lock 1: it cannot --> thread is blocked.

Deadlock!

Answer (score 0):

fge has given a crystal clear answer for your question. but still you might think that why it is not get deadlocked when you run it.

try to add

```
   try
    {
      Thread.sleep(10);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

just after l1.lock();

you will realize how it is possible to get deadlocked.